# How do you copy azure repo folders to a folder on a VM in an Environment in a pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Environment called 'Dev' that has a resource, which is a VM. As part of the 'Dev' pipeline I want to copy files from a specific folder on the develop branch of a specific repo to a specific folder on the VM that's on the Environment.

I've not worked with Environments before or yaml pipelines much but I gather I need to use the CopyFiles@2 task.

So I've got an azure pipeline yaml file something like this:

```
variables:
  isDev: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop')]

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    steps:
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: 'Copy Files'
      inputs:
        contents: 'myFolder\**'
        Overwrite: true
        targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        pathToPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
        artifactName: myArtifact

- stage: Deployment
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.isDev, true))
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy to Dev
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    environment: Dev
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script: echo Foo Bar
```

The first question is how to I get this to copy the files to a specific path on the Dev environment?

Is the PublishBuildArtifacts really needed? The reason I ask is that I want this to copy files every time the pipeline is run and not error if the artifact already exists.

It also feels a bit dirty to have to check the branch is the correct branch this way. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, worked this out with help from this article: https://dev.to/kenakamu/azure-devops-yaml-release-pipeline-trigger-when-build-pipeline-completed-54d5.

I've taken the advice from Daniel Mann regarding the strategy being 'rolling'. I then split my pipeline into 2 pipelines; 1 for building the artifacts and 1 for releasing (copying them).

Answer (score 1):

The deployment strategy you're using relies on specifying an agent pool, which means it **doesn't** run on the machines in the environment. If you use a strategy such as `rolling`, it will run the specified steps on those machines automatically, including any `download` steps to download artifacts.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops#deployment-strategies

You need to publish artifacts as part of the pipeline if you want them to be automatically available to down-stream jobs. Each run will get a different set of artifacts, even if the actual artifact contents are the same.

That said, based on the YAML you posted, you probably don't need to. In fact, you don't need the "build" stage at all. You could just add a `checkout` step during your rolling deployment, and the repo would be cloned on each of the target machines.

Comment: You say I don't need the "build" stage at all and just use a checkout step to clone the repo. I don't want to clone the whole repo, just 2 specific folders (though for now I was just working on one). Would this still work for that?

Comment: @sr28 Your build stage is cloning the entire repo, then pulling out two folders, then uploading them as an artifact. Then your release is downloading the artifact. I don't see why you wouldn't just replace all of that with a single "clone" operation.

Comment: That's not my intention. As I say, I've not worked with yaml pipelines much (normally classic). In reality my goal is simply the question I've asked, but naturally without showing what I've tried it would get closed. So, perhaps my workings so far are confusing things. All I want to do is copy 2 folders from a branch on a repo to a VM that's a resource on an environment.

Comment: @sr28 And the first paragraph of my answer explains how to do that, and includes a link to the relevant documentation that contains examples.

Comment: Yes, but then you go on to say that the build stage isn't necessary and that I could do without it completely. So I'm a little confused. For me to copy 2 folders from the repo to the VM do I still need my build stage, create an artifact, then change my strategy to rolling and include download step to get the artifact?

Comment: @sr28 You don't *need* the build stage and the artifact, but it would still work.

Comment: So in that case would the PublishBuildArtifact just need a 'pathToPublish' and I could do away with the CopyFiles task in the build stage? Then in the deploy step I would need a CopyFiles task to copy the files from Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory to my target folder?